# Queryset takes too long to populate data

Tags: django-views, django-forms

I have a django view that generates a form depending on POST or GET. It works well with little data on the Student model but stagnates when the data gets big. Is there a remedy I can apply??
Here's the `view`

```
def My_View(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            form = NewIssueForm(request.POST,school= request.user.school,pk=pk,issuer = request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                name = form.cleaned_data['borrower_id'].id
                form.save(commit=True)
                books = Books.objects.get(id=pk)
          
                Books.Claimbook(books)
                return redirect('view_books')
                messages.success(request,f'Issued successfully')
        except Exception as e:
            messages.warning(request,f"{e}")
            return redirect('view_books')    
    else:
        form = NewIssueForm(school= request.user.school,pk=pk,issuer = request.user)
    return render(request, 'new_issue.html', {'form': form})
```

Here's the `form`

```
class NewIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args, pk,school,issuer, **kwargs):
        super(NewIssueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        booqs = Books.objects.filter(school=school).get(id=pk)
        self.fields['issuer'].initial = issuer
        self.fields['borrower_id'].Student.objects.filter(school = school)
        self.fields['book_id'].label = str(booqs.book_name) + " - " + str(booqs.reg_no)
        self.fields['book_id'].initial = pk
  
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ['issuer','book_id','borrower_id','due_days']
        widgets = {
            'book_id':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control','type':''}),
            'issuer':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control','type':'hidden'}),
            'borrower_id': Select2Widget(attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Select Student','style':'width:100%','class':'form-control'}),
            'due_days':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
```

Student model

```
class Student(models.Model):                                    
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,help_text="The student's name in full")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    YEAR = [(str(a), str(a)) for a in range(now.year-5, now.year+1)]
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices = YEAR,help_text='The year the student is admitted in school')
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,help_text = "This is the student's admission number")
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    graduated = models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text = "Tick the box to mark the student as graduated")
    prefect = models.BooleanField(default=False,help_text = "Tick the box to select the student as a prefect")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s - F%s %s"%(self.student_id,self.name,self.klass,self.stream)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Students'
        unique_together = ("school", "student_id",)
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['student_id']),
                   models.Index(fields=['name', ]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because when you render the `Student`, it will need to fetch the *related* `Klass` and `Stream` objects, and will make a query *per* `Student` object. This problem is called an *N+1 problem* since fetching *n* student requires one query to fetch all the `Student`s, and then one query per `Student` for the `Klass`es, and one query per `Student` for the `Stream`s.

You can select the data when you select the students with:

```
self.fields['borrower_id'].Student.objects.filter(
    school=school
).select_related('klass', 'stream')
```

Depending on the `__str__` implementations of other models, you might have to select data along with these models as well.

Comment: Why don't you include 'school'  in the select_related list so that we have select_related('school','klass','stream') instead of select_related('klass','stream')?? @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @fakeMake: because your `__str__` does not do anything with the `school`, hence it is not necessary, and will not result in extra queries. Using `.select_related(...)` on a field, loads all the fields of the related model, and thus results in using more *bandwidth*.

Answer (score 0):

Can't guess your model but it seems like select_related may play a trick.

Comment: Just added the model. How would I use that select_related??? I'm new to this...

Comment: It is better to leave a comment if you are unsure about your answer.